# Prove or disprove if $2^n-1$ is composite then n is composite

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove or disprove if $2^n-1$ is composite then n is  composite

my idea:

suppose $2^{-n}$ is composite then for a,b>1

$2^n-1=ab\rightarrow2^n=ab+1\rightarrow n=\log_2^{ab+1}$ is this composite ?

Comment: I think you can use the binomial formula to factor out $2^n-1$.

Comment: First, it's not true: $23|2^{11}-1$.  I'm guessing you want to prove the other direction.  If $n$ is even then it's divisible by $3$.  Otherwise $n=ab$ both odd, greater than $1$ means $2^a-1$ divides $2^n-1$.

Comment: $2^n-1$ (for $n\in \Bbb N$) is called a Mersenne number. If $2^n-1$ is prime then $n$ must be prime. But if $n$ is prime then $2^n-1$ may fail to be prime. It is conjectured but not proven that there are infinitely many Mersenne primes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Put $n=11$ and observe that $2^{11}-1 = 23 \times 89$.

Comment: Dear Math Lover, I admire your answer at MSE. Can I ask you to look at my problem,Please?, if you have few minutes..?..Best Regards. thank you so much.. by the way, our name is the same :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559814/is-the-proof-i-am-using-sufficient-correct-for-the-system-of-equation

Comment: @MathLover Your solution seems to be fine. See the comments of Jack D'Aurizio to the question you linked. I think your comments on this solution will appear as an inbox message to the person who asked the question. So it is nice if we do not exchange further comments here.

Comment: I thought you would answer/comment the question directly :) .. Thank you again...